# What is a wedge product?

Tags: calculus, tensor-products

What is actually a wedge product ? How does it differ from a tensor product ? What is the intuition to invoke such a product, kind of like tensor product is invoked to simplify multilinear maps ?

Comment: Check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554724/why-it-makes-sense-to-think-of-multivectors-as-paralelograms/554784#554784 for an easy geoemtrical interpretation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up Cauchy-Binet formulas. There the determinant of a Gramian matrix 
$$\det(\;(\,\langle a_i,b_j\rangle\,)_{i,j=1}^d\;)=\langle a_1∧a_2∧...∧a_d,\,b_1∧b_2∧...∧b_d\rangle$$ 
is the euclidean scalar product of the outer products of the (column) vectors $a_1,...,a_d$ and $b_1,...,b_d\in \Bbb R^n$, $n\ge d$.

So in some sense, the outer product is a "square root" of the Gramian determinant. And that determinant plays an important part in differential geometry.